# What happens when jni library is loaded again?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

So as the title says if i don't unload library and load it again by System.loadLibrary() then what will happen?

Will it take space in memory again or previous allocated mem will be used.

Android Dalvik machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik, If the library has loaded then If you load same library again anywhere then that call will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not reloaded. On the Operating System level, a reference count on the library is increased. A well-written JVM will balance this by native calls to free the library as the JVM shuts down.